# Reverse a mod in an equation

Tags: linear-algebra, chinese-remainder-theorem

Being quick and to the point, I have the following equation.

```
       (A * M)%F = B
```

I want to solve for M. How do you move the modular F?

Comment: the answer relies on multiplying $B$ by the multiplicative inverse of $A$. $$M \equiv A^{-1}B \pmod F$$ See the wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse for details

Comment: You don't move it, you just pretend it's not there. Note that mod F applies to the whole expression, not just the left or right hand side so it's more of a decoration than a part of the equation.

Comment: @CyclotomicField I like to say it's part of the $\equiv$. Which very much isn't decoration, it's a fundamental part of the relation. But it's not directly manipulatable through standard equation manipulation rules.